# Ordered insertion of data with parallel processing in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, parallel-processing

Here's my Ruby code

The method `getLikes()` fetches the Facebook likes in a `hash` format of the user with token `t`

```
def multi
    token = ["Facebook token 1","Facebook token 2","Facebook token 3",...]
    @data = []
    @threads = []

    token.each do |t|
        @threads << Thread.new{@data << getLikes(t)}
    end

    @threads.each do |th|
        th.join
    end


    render json: @data
end
```

The problem is that the data that `@data`'s contents are not in the same order because of the parralization.

To fix this, I modified the first loop to

```
i = 0
token.each do |t|
    @threads << Thread.new{@data[i] = getLikes(t)}
    i = i + 1
end
```

But then the program does not wait for all the threads to finish. I get a few `null` values in the `@data` array.

What would be a good way to go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your code is not thread-safe as it uses a shared-variable among threads without using mutexes. Hashes are not thread-safe in Ruby.

The solution is to return simple values in your threads, and aggregate the results in your main code. To keep the order, simply return the token along with the value:

```
def multi
  token = ["Facebook token 1","Facebook token 2","Facebook token 3",...]
  @threads = []

  token.each do |t|
    @threads << Thread.new{[t, getLikes(t)]}
  end

  data = Hash[@threads.map(&:value)] # this will block the main thread

  sorted_data = []
  token.each do |t|
    sorted_data << data[t]
  end

  render json: sorted_data
end
```

Comment: Thanks, This works great.
One question though.
What does
`data = Hash[@threads.map(&:value)]`
do?

Comment: I was just editing the code to add a comment about that ;D It blocks the main thread and gets the value from each thread. The 'value' of a thread is the value of the last expression in the Thread's block so in that case, it is the array [t, getLikes(t)].

You can learn more in the Ruby doc: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-i-value

Comment: And Hash[] is just a cute way to build a Hash from an Array of Arrays. The first value of each array is the key, the second is the value for the corresponding key.

As of Ruby 2.1, you can use the more readable 'to_h' on an array of arrays to achieve the same.

Comment: Nice solution.  I didn't know about Thread#value; I'll be making use of that in the future.  Would this code work without the hash?  i.e., `data = @threads.map(&:value)` and then `sorted_data = data.sort_by(&:first)`.

Comment: I was thinking about using sort_by at first, but then realized that his original array of tokens was not necessarily ordered. My solution keeps the original order no matter what, but is a bit less elegant than simply using sort_by.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
token.each_with_index do |t, 1|
  @threads << Thread.new{@data[i] = getLikes(t)}
end
```

The problem with your `i = i + 1` solution is that the value of `i` in the Thread block is taken *when the block is run*, and not when it is declared. This means that you might get one or two items in some spot in the middle of the array, but most of your threads will take the last value of `i`, and override each other at the last position of the array...